# Gradle native libraries not found on device but present in apk

Tags: java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, twilio, here-api, libs

My application uses [Here SDK](https://developer.here.com) and [Twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android). Both uses native libraries (Here SDK with native libraries locally plugged in from /libs and /jniLibs folders, Twilio SDK plugged in from jCenter). But on Android 5.1 Here SDK throws exception "MISSING LIBRARIES: libMAPSJNI.so" although this library present in result APK. I opened folder where my program is installed on device and compared content in two cases: with or without Twilio SDK. The difference is that when connected Twilio API folder /lib is a file, and for obvious reasons, the loader can not see inside it native libraries needed initialize Here SDK. If remove the Twilio gradle dependency the assembly occurs normally. What could be a reason and how to fix it? If needed I can attach test project with these libs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to modify your **build.gradle** like this:

```
android {
    (...)
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

It's probably because Twilio SDK supports x86 and HERE SDK currently doesn't support it.

Comment: Hey Artem, Thanks for jumping in for the Twilio community here. Can we send you a shirt to share our appreciation? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Comment: This applies for other architectures there HERE SDK does not support as well (such as arm64-v8a)

Answer (score 1):

By defining a `splits` block you can tell Gradle to create [APKs for each listed ABI](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split):

```
include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
```

Alternatively you can include all desired ABIs into **one** APK by adding the following filter:

```
android {
(...)
defaultConfig {
    (...)
    ndk {
        // allow only 32bit *.so libs
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

}

Both approaches will exclude 64bit functionality that might clash with the 32bit [HERE SDK](https://developer.here.com/), but the latter will support more devices with a single APK.

Some libraries, like the new [Android Room Persistence](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) library, add 32bit flavors along with the two 64bit ABI flavors **arm64-v8a** and **x86_64**. Since [HERE SDK](https://developer.here.com/) at the moment only provides a 32bit lib it should be safe to exclude 64bit lib variants. On the other hand it is expected that 64bit devices can gracefully handle 32bit libs.