# HERE SDK Missing Library error Android 6.0

Tags: android, here-api

I have an application which runs perfectly on Android devices and emulators < Android 6.0, but devices and emulator running Android 6.0+ I get the error MISSING_LIBRARIES when initializing the map fragment.

I have tried to compile against V23 as well as V21, same problem.
I have implemented the V6.0 permissions still not working.
I have installed the BasicMapSolution project, still not working (compiled V21)

Please help as the project is to go live soon.

Comment: Very clever to not tell which libraries. Apparently `prefers to keep an air of mystery` is for your posts too.

Comment: Please check LogCat and provide any details you may be able to find there (try looking for the "`MapsEngine`" tag). Also, you can find more details about the `Error` by calling `Error#getDetails()` and `Error#getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion AndrewJC, I have checked the details on the error object and this is the error: lib/libMAPSJNI.so not found. The weird part is the application is working on older Android devices, so the file "should" be there for all?

Comment: Please let us know which SDK revision you are using?

Comment: @DavidLeong We are using: HERE_Android_SDK_Premium_v3.2.1_439

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle native libraries not found on device but present in apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021240/gradle-native-libraries-not-found-on-device-but-present-in-apk)

Answer (score 2):

Please check next things:

1) Setup SDK accordingly to https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html
Make sure that you put **armeabi-v7a** folder with all it's content into **/src/main/jniLibs**

2) If you are using any other 3rd party dependencies which have native code, then modify your **build.gradle** like this:

```
android {
    ...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I have checked the jniLibs folder as well as the unzipped APK and both folders contains all the required library files as well as the specific one from the error. (libMapsJNI.so)

Comment: Did you try to modify build.gradle file as described in step 2?

Answer (score 0):

like Artem Nikitin wrote include a armeabi-v7a folder within /src/main/jniLibs this should help. Its contents are within the HERE.sdk. But now you will need a real Android-Device to Test your app.