# Here SDK- MISSING_LIBRARIES on certain Samsung phones

Tags: java, android

I am integrating Here Premium SDK in my Android app. The integration works fine on most of the devices. But On certain phones like Samsung Galaxy S7, the map doesn't show and I am getting a MISSING LIBRARIES Error.

I checked with HERE MAPS System Requirements in the following link and I think S7 is a ARM based device.

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/system-requirements.html

Does anyone else face this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle native libraries not found on device but present in apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021240/gradle-native-libraries-not-found-on-device-but-present-in-apk)

Comment: check architecture. in case it armv8 (not v7) try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021240/gradle-native-libraries-not-found-on-device-but-present-in-apk it should helps