# MISSING_LIBRARIES when using the Here SDK on Android

Tags: android, here-api

We are trying to integrate the HERE SDK on our Android app, and are getting a `MISSING_LIBRARIES` error in `onEngineInitializationCompleted`.

We are seeing this on real devices (Sony XPeria Z5 and on Samsung Galaxy S8).

The strange thing is that the sample app bundled with the SDK (BasicMapSolution) does work.  We cannot seem to see any difference between the working sample and our own app.

Also the fact that the error is about missing libraries is puzzling.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the `getDetails()` API of `OnEngineInitListener#Error` indicating? If you are including the HERE SDK AAR in the same way as in BasicMapSolution it should work. All of the required libraries for the HERE SDK (native and Java) are bundled in the AAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SDK version with *.so files, then make sure that *.so files are located by path `/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/`.

Otherwise, this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021670/4816308

Comment: That was it.  We use Realm in our application, which has native libraries for all ABIs, which results in this issue.  The solution (with `splits`) for the question you linked to did work.

Comment: Glad to help :)