# HERE SDK libraries missing. gnustl_shared

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

I am trying to use the latest HERE SDK. I followed all the instruction from the documentation.

HERE Android SDK Premium Edition v3.5

ERROR "initialize map engine status Native libraries missing: gnustl_shared. Please refer to the user guide for details about proper project setup."

Comment: This one solved the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021240/gradle-native-libraries-not-found-on-device-but-present-in-apk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle native libraries not found on device but present in apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021240/gradle-native-libraries-not-found-on-device-but-present-in-apk)

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

You need to modify your build.gradle like this:

```
android {
    (...)
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

It's probably because Twilio SDK supports x86 and HERE SDK currently doesn't support it.